# How to do Modal Popup for particular row of webgrid in mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am using a webgrid to display data.I have used edit button by using actionlink and everything is working fine. Now i have to modify the editing in a sense that the editing data should come as a popup modal so everyone can edit the webgrid. Here is the working code for webgrid which has editing functionality which I need to modify as a popup modal

```
<style type="text/css">
    .webGrid { margin: 4px; border-collapse: collapse; width: 500px;  background-color:#B4CFC3;}
    .header { background-color: #C1D4E6; font-weight: bold; color: #FFF; }
    .webGrid th, .webGrid td { border: 1px solid #C0C0C0; padding: 5px; }
    .alt { background-color: #E4E9F5; color: #000; }
    .gridHead a:hover {text-decoration:underline;}
    .description { width:auto}
    .select{background-color: #71857C}
</style>
@{

    var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model,
                                           defaultSort: "First Name",
                                           rowsPerPage:5, fieldNamePrefix:"wg_",
                                           canPage:true,canSort:true,
                                           pageFieldName:"pg",sortFieldName:"srt"
                                           );  
 }



<div id="gridContent">
    @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webGrid",
            headerStyle: "header",
            alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
            selectedRowStyle: "select",
            columns: grid.Columns(
            //grid.Column("Id", format: (item) => item.GetSelectLink(item.Id)),
                    //grid.Column("id", format: (item) => item.GetSelectLink(item.id)),
            grid.Column("cityname","cityname" ),
            grid.Column("citypopulation", "citypopulation", style: "description"),
            grid.Column("country", "country"),

            grid.Column(format: (item) =>  Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.id }))


        )


             //grid.Column(header: "Edit", format: @<text>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.id })</text>, style: "colOperation")

    //hggh
     )) 
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

i did like this but it is creating same page again donwside and then same page in popup and finally going in to the edit page which i already created. i dont know what went wrong

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $(".popupLink").click(function (e) {
        var url = this.href;
        var dialog = $("#dialog");
        if ($("#dialog").length == 0) {
            dialog = $('<div id="dialog" style="display:hidden"></div>').appendTo('body');
        }
        dialog.load(
            url,
            {}, // omit this param object to issue a GET request instead a POST request, otherwise you may provide post parameters within the object
            function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                dialog.dialog({                       
                    close: function (event, ui) {                            
                        dialog.remove();
                    },
                    modal: true,                        
                    width: 460, resizable: false
                });
            }
        );           
        return false;           
    });
});
</script>
```

in grid

```
grid.Column(format: (item) =>  Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.id }, new { @class = "popupLink" }))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not state clear about what your modal window code looks like but assuming that you are using a 3rd party modal window files (.JS files, a few s (overlay and may be the modal window itself), and some CSS with it. If that is the case then just have

Add a property to you anchor tag `onclick="PopUpUpdateProductNameDialog('1'))"`

```
<a href="#" onclick="PopUpUpdateProductNameDialog('11')', 'SomeString', 'Pass As Many Parameters' )" class="md-trigger" data-modal="ModalDIVIDDependsOnWhatStructureYouUsing" >
```

Make sure all you .JS files are loaded as well as CSS, and HTML.

[Modal Windows Demo](http://tympanus.net/Development/ModalWindowEffects/)

Comment: i updated question,presently everything work fine, but while editing instead of coming record in new page i want it in a popup window

Comment: I just added an example of how it may look. You have to figure out how the modal files communicate and structure you anchor tag accordingly.

Comment: What is the HTML output of this? 'grid.Column(format: (item) =>  Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.id }, new { @class = "popupLink" }))'